# Not working properly while using S7GraphView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to draw a line graph in iphone and am using S7GraphView for it.But when I compile my app it is showing so many errors like:

```
"CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextFillRect", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextSetLineDash", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextClosePath", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
  "_CGContextFillPath", referenced from:
      -[S7GraphView drawRect:] in S7GraphView.o
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I found answer myself.Thank you all for helping me.I have not added CoreGraphics framework properly.When I added it through Build Phases it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

Try linking you application to `Quartz.framework` and/or `QuartzCore.framework`.

Comment: Yes.I have added QuartzCore framework.But now also showing same errors